# In R how to control multi-threading in BLAS parallel matrix product

Tags: r, multithreading, matrix, blas

I have a question regarding the use of BLAS parallelized matrix product in R (being the default matrix product at least since R-3.4, maybe earlier).

The default behavior (at least on my machine) is now for the matrix product (c.f. example below) to use all the cores available on the machine, which can be a problem.

Do you know how to control the number of cores used for standard matrix product in R?

Thanks in advance

Example:

```
n=10000
p=1000
q=5000
A = matrix(runif(n*p),nrow=n, ncol=p)
B = matrix(runif(p*q),nrow=p, ncol=q)
C = A %*% B # multi-threaded matrix product
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=fr_FR.utf8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package [RhpcBLASctl](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RhpcBLASctl) does *just* that.

From its DESCRIPTION:

> Control the number of threads on 'BLAS' (Aka 'GotoBLAS', 'ACML' and 'MKL'). and possible to control the number of threads in 'OpenMP'. get a number of logical cores and physical cores if feasible.

We mention it in the [CRAN Task View on HPC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is just what I need. I did search for something like that before asking my question here but could not find it.

I think I will contact the R core team regarding this matter. The doc (matmult) is not clear on this point. The default behavior to use all available cores in matrix product can be a huge problem on shared computing resources. 

Thanks again

Comment: I was commuting to work and did not get a chance to comment. I was expectecting pretty much the answer Tomas gave you on r-devel.  This *is* documented in the case of the (Intel-based) MKL, OpenBLAS, ... via known environment variables, the available BLAS choices are documented within R, and in short you have no issue here.  *You* (or your sysadmin) chose to install OpenBLAS; R has no bearing on that. We (in Debian / Ubuntu) give you a choice of several BLAS implementations.  All this has been disussed a million times here, on the R lists, and in other places for many years.  Nothing new here.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. My concern was mainly for users of one of my packages that combines 'parallel' package multi-threading and matrix product. However, I understand now that it is their responsability to know how their BLAS implementations works.